# Change Panorama control title movement amount

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to change the movement amount of the title of a panorama control in a windows phone 8 application when you move between panorama items?

the logo in my app is moving way too much that you can only see a small part of it in the last panorama item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do so.....

Comment: How did you conclude on this? Have you got any official reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Storyboard` to manually slow down the animation of the background `Image` by hitting property i6n `Storyboard` `Transform.x`.

Comment: Slowing down the background is different than slowing down the header, isn't it?